# JBOSS EAP 7.1 : NoSuchMethodError: org.jboss.as.ejb3.logging.EjbLogger.tracef(Ljava/lang/String;I)V

Tags: jboss, ejb, ejb-3.0

so im using the getRollBackOnly method located under EjbComponent class that implements org.jboss.logging.BasicLogger interface :

```
 public boolean getRollbackOnly() throws IllegalStateException {
if (isBeanManagedTransaction())
  throw EjbLogger.ROOT_LOGGER.failToCallgetRollbackOnly(); 
try {
  TransactionManager tm = getTransactionManager();
  if (tm.getTransaction() == null)
    throw EjbLogger.ROOT_LOGGER.failToCallgetRollbackOnlyOnNoneTransaction(); 
  int status = tm.getStatus();
  EjbLogger.ROOT_LOGGER.tracef("Current transaction status is %d", status); //this ligne is causing the error
  switch (status) {
    case 3:
    case 4:
      throw EjbLogger.ROOT_LOGGER.failToCallgetRollbackOnlyAfterTxcompleted();
    case 1:
    case 9:
      return true;
  } 
  return false;
} catch (SystemException se) {
  EjbLogger.ROOT_LOGGER.getTxManagerStatusFailed((Throwable)se);
  return true;
}
```

EJBLogger interface target line :

```
public static final EjbLogger ROOT_LOGGER = (EjbLogger)Logger.getMessageLogger(EjbLogger.class, "org.jboss.as.ejb3");
```

the exception that i had :

```
   Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jboss.as.ejb3.logging.EjbLogger.tracef(Ljava/lang/String;I)V                                                                        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.EJBComponent.getRollbackOnly(EJBComponent.java:358)                                                                                      at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.session.SessionBeanComponent.getRollbackOnly(SessionBeanComponent.java:100)                                                              at org.jboss.as.ejb3.context.EJBContextImpl.getRollbackOnly(EJBContextImpl.java:90)                                                                                     at org.jboss.as.ejb3.context.SessionContextImpl.getRollbackOnly(SessionContextImpl.java:133)
```

does anyone know why I'm getting this error? 
ps:i have already jboss-logging jar

thanks .

Comment: Are you using the `EjbLogger` in your deployment? That's not meant to be used outside of the server itself. Also make sure you're not including the jboss-logging library in your deployment.

Comment: Hi James thanks for your quick response, actually I'm trying to deploy a multitenancy application on Jboss eap 7.1 server and, i am testing the method setRollBackOnly() under EjbLogger by using a not existing shema but it throws the error message mentioned previously wish i believe it is not the expected behavior.

Comment: So this is for a test case? If so maybe you've got the wrong version of jboss-logging on the class path.

Comment: Actually im using jboss-logging 3.1.0 GA with wildfly-ejb3-7.1.0.GA-redhat-11 ( ps: i don't have jboss-logging lib in my application )

Comment: thanks , i have fixed the problem by using the latest version of this lib ( jboss-logging-3.4.1.Final)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for whom who got the exception, i have fixed the problem by using the latest version of jboss-logging library ( jboss-logging-3.4.1.Final)